# Understanding the definition of reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, reductions

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_%28complexity%29):

> Given two subsets A and B of N and a set of functions F from N to N
>   which is closed under composition, A is called reducible to B under F
>   if $$
>      \exists f \in F \mbox{ . } \forall x \in \mathbb{N} \mbox{ . } x \in A \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in B $$ We write $$
>      A \leq_{F} B $$ Let S be a subset of P(N) and ≤ a reduction, then S is called closed under ≤ if $$
>      \forall s \in S \mbox{ . } \forall A \in P(\mathbb{N}) \mbox{ . } A \leq s \Rightarrow A \in S $$ A subset A of N is called hard for S
>   if $$
>      \forall s \in S \mbox{ . } s \leq A $$ A subset A of N is called complete for S if A is hard for S and A is in S.

I am trying to relate the above definitions to those for problems: problem A can be reduced to problem B, a set of problems are NP-hard, a set of problems are NP-complete. But I don't know how to relate. I think one link I am missing is to see how a subset of problem can be seen as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: In my experience, it often helps to check the definitions in a textbook. Wikipedia is often hopeless with TCS content.

Comment: What books do you recommend?

Comment: @Tim There's a nice preprint available online: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms.html
If you're going to be studying computer science, it's a nice one to own.

Comment: Chapter 8 of Algorithm Design by Kleinberg and Tardos is also good. I consider that one worth owning as well if you're going to be spending a lot of time in theoretical computer science. The solved exercises are excellent for learning.

Comment: CLRS is the standard reference. It has probably covers the most material of any algorithms book, but it's not quite as accessible. http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844

Comment: @Tim All of these should be available at a decent university library

Comment: @Raphael- that is so true. A question on one of my exams was "what is wrong with this definition of strong np hardness from wikipedia?" (The definition given was way off)

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: Where is the link to that one? Is it correct now?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete - I don't remember the exact wording of the original, but they forgot the part about it having to be unary- the defintion given was just the same as for regular NP-hardness. OT perhaps. Sorry.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks! I will check them out when I get the oppotunity to read them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition you're quoting is very abstract, but the concepts you're trying to understand are pretty intuitive. A problem $A$ is NP-hard if you can solve any problem in NP using it. This means that any $B \in NP$ can be reduced to $A$, i.e. there is some polytime function $f$ such that $x \in B$ iff $f(x) \in A$; so you can test whether $x \in B$ by computing $f(x)$ and test whether the latter is in $A$.

A problem is NP-complete if it is both in NP-hard and in NP. This means that it is hardest among problems in NP. A problem can be NP-hard without being in NP, for example the halting problem.

You're mentioning sets of problems as belonging to NP, but that's a typing error: members of NP are problems, in the guise of subsets of the set of natural numbers (or of the set of finite binary strings, which is the same). The subset specifies the set of inputs for which the problem has the answer YES.

Comment: Thanks! (1) when you wrote $x\in B$, do you treat $B$ as the set of solutions for problem B, and $x$ is one of the solution? (2) "members of NP are problems, in the guise of subsets of the set of natural numbers (or of the set of finite binary strings, which is the same). The subset specifies the set of inputs for which the problem has the answer YES." Do you mean a problem corresponds to a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ or of $\Sigma^*$ for some alphabet $\Sigma$, by the subset being a set of inputs for which the problem has answer YES?

Comment: (3) Do "a solution to a problem" and "an input for which the problem has answer YES" mean the same? (4) Are the problems in discussion some special kind of problems?

Comment: (4) Does $x \in B$ iff $f(x) \in A$ mean the same as $f(B)=A$? Is $f$ not necessarily injective?

Comment: @Tim The syntax is similar to that used for languages. Here $x$ is an input, $B$ is "a decision problem" or "the set of inputs for which a correct algorithm for the decision problem outputs yes".

Comment: @Tim (1) We think of each "problem" as a property of the input. The set corresponding to the problem consists of these inputs for which the property holds. (2) $\mathbb{N}$ can be identified as the set of finite strings over some finite alphabet $\Sigma$. For example, for $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ you can take the encoding which drops the MSB of the binary encoding of the number. So $5$ would code 01 and $13$ would code 101. (3) A solution to a problem, in this context, is an algorithm for it, which decides whether the input satisfies the property given by the problem. [cont.]

Comment: @Tim (4) All problems are decision problems. That is, each input either satisfies the property or doesn't satisfy it. In complexity theory we also often consider optimization problem, in which the challenge is to optimize some quantity under some constraints.

Comment: Thanks, Yuval! Does x∈B iff f(x)∈A mean the same as f(B)=A? Is f not necessarily injective?

Comment: $x \in B$ iff $f(x) \in A$ doesn't mean the same as $f(B) = A$, for many reasons. First, $f(B) = A$ doesn't guarantee that $f(x) \notin A$ for $x \notin B$. Second, the image of $f$ doesn't have to be all of $A$, indeed this is rarely the case. An equivalent statement would be $f(B) \subseteq A$ and $f(\overline{B}) \subseteq \overline{A}$.

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily injective. Indeed, often the first step is to recognize some "easy" instances and then solve them directly by outputting some fixed YES or NO instance of $A$.

Comment: I understand the matching on one value (e.g. 'YES') of a boolean test suffices for defining subsetting for boolean problems, yet afaics that Wikipedia definition doesn't appear to be general enough to handle non-boolean problems. Rather we would need to write a definition with tuples on pairs of (input, output) e.g. *(x, g(x)) ∈ B* and *(f(x), g(x)) ∈ A* for the general case?